# Why doesn't my Java process get more real memory?

Tags: java, memory, io

I'm probably doing something stupid, but I need 100 GB for it. I'm allocating them using [memory mapped files](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm) at start up and it happens nearly instantly. As I have only 32 GB of physical memory, I rearranged the program, so that it works with a 20 GB chunk and only after doing a lot of work switches to another one. I'm starting the process with `-mx24G` on a Linux box.

What happens is that it never gets near the end of the first chunk. The CPU is mostly idle, the HD is very busy all the time. The process never takes more than maybe 6 GB, which explains why it can't do any progress (the locality is very terrible and nearly each memory access is a page fault).

But why doesn't the process take more real memory? There are still 15 GB free and quite some processes could be swapped away easily.

---

The files get created at the very beginning of the process and are therefore empty. It looks like the process was indeed *needlessly* fetching empty pages. So I prepended a sequential scan and now my process quickly gets its 20 GB. But that's about all...

The CPU is still idle, as if each memory access was *write-through* to disk. What's going on?

Comment: What expensive operation are you doing?

Comment: Reading in 20 GB of data via random access is gonna take a *very* long time. (hours?) How long did you wait before you finally killed it?

Comment: @Mysticial: I'm not reading any data in, I'm creating new files, so *nothing* needs to be read. It was maybe one hour, maybe more.

Comment: @Sri Harsha Chilakapati: I'm trying to solve an Euler project problem in a probably very stupid way.

Comment: Read or write, it doesn't matter. Random access is going to be painfully slow. Random access of <4k chunks on a mechanical hard drive typically yields <1 MB/s of speed. For 20 GB, that's 20,000 seconds or 5.6 hours - at the least.

Comment: @Mysticial: You might be right, but at this step neither reads nor writes are necessary. The memory is fresh, there's nothing to load and no need to store anything yet. But I'll give it a try a do a sequential scan of the chunk before I start the computation.